# Highcharts breaks up my data array in a strange way

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=line-basic&theme=dark-green) (link to a specific demo -- click View Options to compare below code) to render some data for personal-use.

[Note: this is almost definitely a me-related error, so I don't mean to insinuate that Highcharts is at fault -- it's really a wonderful api!]

When setting the *series.data* field of the chart object, I encounter strange array sectioning.

For instance, this works fine:

```
series: [{
    name: 'seriesName',
    data: [22, 24, 15]
}]
```

And three data points are plotted with values 22, 24 and 15.

However,

```
series: [{
    name: 'sillySeries',
    data: chartData[0]
}]
```

renders 3 points with the values 2, 4 and 5 and the titles of the points are 2, 2 and 1 respectively... that is, it's splitting the array entries into a title and then a value for two-digit numbers.

console.log shows me that chartData looks like

```
22,24,15,2010-9,2010-10,2010-11
```

(3 values for 3 months)

Although the actual arrays are more like [22,24,15][2010-9,2010-10,2010-11]

My 2d-array `chartData[][]` has `[column][row]` indices for the data, and I figured that asking for `chartData[0]` would return an array.

Perhaps my question should be: How do I return a 1d array from a 2d array representation for setting properties/values in javascript objects?  It seems like I'm probably overlooking something very obvious.

---

edit:

```
data: [24]
```

plots one point at 24, awesome.

```
data: '24'
```

splits up the data as title and then value, effectively plotting a point at 4 and not 24.

So the representation becomes a string when I try to pass an array to the *data* field.  Any way I can do like string.toArray ?

---

edit 2:

`chartData[col][row]` is declared as an empty array

```
var chartData = [];
```

and subsequently filled up with values by iterating over an HTML table's rows and columns, where the innermost loop contents look like

```
chartData[cellIndex][rowIndex] = $(currentCell).text();
```

Comment: aren't you missing the row in the chartData array?

Comment: @yoda: chartData[0][0] returns one data point, with title 2 and value 2 (although it should be 22).  I'm trying to set _data_ to an array, which is effectively one "dimension" of the chartData array, i.e. a column

Comment: so the problem basically is that the order of the arrays appear messed up, right?

Comment: @yoda: your comment helped me realize that it's representing the array data as a string when I pass it.  Check out the edit; any thoughts kind sir?

Comment: got one question : where and how do you define charData?

Comment: @yoda: edited my question, let me know if that's not enough info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parseInt() saved the day.

something like

```
for (i=0; i<chartData[0].length; ++i) {
    columnOne.push(parseInt(chartData[0][i]);
}
```

gave me an array that I could then use to display the data with the data field in the object notation

```
data: columnOne
```

or more literally

chart1.series[0].data = columnOne;

Thank you James for pointing out

> While chartData is probably an array, it sounds like chartData[0] is a string.

which lead to my discovery that the data in my array was actually all strings, which I kept this way because some fields are strings, some are dates (YYYY-MM-DD) and some are just ints.

Many thanks to you both =)

Comment: @RaoulGeorge I know this is a pretty old post but I just wanted to say NP! ^.^

Answer (score 2):

While chartData is probably an array, it sounds like chartData[0] is a string.  When you use an array index on a string you get the character at that position, which is exactly what you are experiencing...

> renders 3 points with the values 2, 4 and 5 and the titles of the points are 2, 2 and 1 respectively... that is, it's splitting the array entries into a title and then a value for two-digit numbers.

There are many ways to define arrays within arrays in javascript; here is one:

```
var chartData = [
  [22,24,15]
  ,['2010-9','2010-10','2010-11']
];
```

Comment: Defining the array statically is fine, but I am using a variable (changing) array to draw my table (runs a query, gets some data from the server, fills up the array);  but I'll see if this sort of declaration can help

Comment: I understand your answer better today, do you know how I can make the <code>data</code> parameter recognize my array entries as numbers and not take the whole thing as a string?  I tried using something like a columnOne.push(chartData[0][i]) in a loop to extract the first column into a new array, but I still get the string indexing problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a real answer, but might help you.

Highcharts enables you to preprocess certain options. In your case, you could do something like :

```
options.series[0].data = new Array(1, 0, 4);
```

doc reference : http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#options

If this fails, comment above.

Comment: if I do data: new Array(chartData[0]) I get a point title of 22, a y-value of 24, and an x-value of the date.  I don't care to name each point, but this was revelatory in how the array information is parsed, as __title,value__ for each array index...  Maybe I will just add dummy values although none of the demo graphs seem to exhibit this behavior (!)

Comment: You weren't supposed to use it that way (new Array(char..). Just put the array you have as value.